# Formating a string without having to make countless manipulations

Tags: c#, string

While parsing through an html web document, I end up having strings that might look like this:

"Blades of Steel                                    \n                                    \n                                    \n                                    \n                                    \nTypical - Your Situation                                    \n                                    28\n                                    347\n                                    \n $8.47                                     \n                                    \n1234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132"

All I want in this string is those values:

- A string "Blades of Steel"
- An int for value $8.47

How could I parse through the string easily without having to do multiple `string.Replace` or `string.Split`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the format you can do like this:

```
  string first = yourString.Split('\n')[0]; //Blades of Steel
  string second = yourString.Split('\n')[9]; //$8.47
```

Comment: You could also split the string *once*, which could be a lot faster depending on the string's length

Comment: @Nolonar Obviously yes. but I want to avoid more lines.

Comment: @Nolonar I cannot assure the string's length as the information will change from times to times.

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad your solution works. Thanks! Simple and efficient.

Comment: @HerveS what about the number of `\n` characters befor `$`? do they change?

Comment: I will need to try further on, but I think that this will remain static, so I'm fairly confident that what you propose should work fine.

Comment: I have a slight problem with what I actually obtain. The first string, for example, will be "Blades of Steel              " with plenty of empty spaces. I'd like only to retain "Blades of Steel", how could I do that?

Comment: @HerveS Use this: `yourString.Split('\n')[0].Trim()`

Answer (score 4):

If you know the format in advance, you can writer a regular expression to parse it.

Comment: I don't know how regular expressions works, could you give me an example?

Comment: Take a look at examples in MSDN documentation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kweb790z.aspx . Learning regurlar expression will take some time, but it is a worthy investment.

Comment: On my way! I've heard about it for a few times, but haven't took time to learn it. Looks like it's time I try my hand at it. Thank you